# Select max and min date from registers

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select

I have a table with these columns: `product`, `date` in MySQL database. The table saves access to the product with the date.

```
Product | Date

p1      | '2016-07-03 10:00:09.368000'

p2      | '2016-07-03 10:00:24.872000'

p1      | '2016-07-03 10:00:59.070000'

p2      | '2016-07-03 10:01:00.948000'
```

I'm trying to obtain (for each product) the max and the min date the product has been accessed but in just one query, I've been trying many things, and I haven´t found a good solution.
Any ideas?

Comment: is it date field is date formate

Comment: Yes is date formate.

Comment: have you tried MIN, MAX function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
SELECT 
    Product,
    MAX(`Date`) AS maxDate,
    MIN(`Date`) AS minDate
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Product
```

Comment: Yes that is, many thanks, I'm new in sql, and was traying with examples more complicated.